# Phase Change Materials Charge and Discharge

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, chemical-engineering

Is there a way to approximate the charge and discharge time of a PCM. I understand that this is a transient process as a material melts from the outside in, but I was wondering it there a means of estimating this time in order to determine the charge and discharge cycles. I am looking for a good source that shows different melting times, steady state calcs or published data.

I have been looking at different vendors of these materials but their tech sheets rarely include this info. I am particularly interested in Eutectic salts if anyone has a good source on this sort of info.

Thanks in advance,

Regards

P

Comment: Do you want to model a given shape, or do you want the volume thermal conductivity of each phase?  What are your external  (thermal) interfaces?  As written, it's hard to figure out what you actually need.